# Windows 10 desktop Icons rearrange when I change displays

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop, desktop-icons

I have two displays. Monitor 1 is 60hz 2650 x 1440

Monitor 2 is actually a drawing tablet, 1920 x 1080.

I've had the tablet for a year and the monitor since I got my computer in 2017, but lately, I don't know if it was from an update or from when Dad and I cloned the HDD onto an SSD, but any time I switch displays back to the main monitor after using to the tablet, all of my desktop icons are crammed into the top left of the main monitor.

Note: This did not always happen, I just tried downloading the latest drivers for the tablet and my computer stays up to date automatically.

I'm aware that icons move themselves when the resolution changes, mine did too at one point, but now it  they don't return to their relative positions when I switch back to the monitor.

Comment: Another note is that this doesn't happen when I extend the display. 

I just don't wanna burn out my main display if I'm only using the tablet, y'know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior of Windows changes without explanation from time to time.
I myself have given up on trying to force Windows to keep my icons in place,
so I use third-party products to do that for me.

Below are two free products that will save and restore desktop layout:

- [Iconoid](http://www.sillysot.com/)
- [ReIcon](https://www.sordum.org/8366/reicon-v1-9-restore-desktop-icon-layouts/)

Undoubtedly more such products do exist besides the above two.

Comment: Thanks man, but I'm hoping I can get a fix without having to install things. Not that I'm untrusting but I have a list of programs I installed over minor inconveniences so long that I detest the idea of needing to install another. But if there's no other fix, I guess I'll try this! thx again

Comment: Hey, funnily enough, as soon as I installed the program, I tried to cause the thing again and guess what....

It didn't do the thing. Technology man, technology.

Comment: It comes and it goes. I rarely need to use these programs, but they are life-savers when it happens (I have LOTS of icons).